# Convert double value to a char array in C

Tags: c, arrays, char, double

How do I convert double value to a char array in C?

```
double a=2.132;
char arr[8];
```

Is there any way to do this in standard C? Can anyone give any solution?

Comment: I'm not sure if you mean you want the string "2.132" or if you mean something more nefarious?

Comment: i want to store double a value in to the char array as characters.

Answer (score 14):

If you are about to store the double DATA, not the readable representation, then:

```
#include <string.h>

double a=2.132;
char arr[sizeof(a)];
memcpy(arr,&a,sizeof(a));
```

Comment: Your parentheses around 'a' after the sizeof operator are not needed.  (Parentheses are needed when the argument is a a type name rather than an entity.)

Comment: More readable for me. I do even tend to write " if ( (good) && (!best) ) ...". But you're right.

Comment: @vmatyi I don't think you want to dereference the array as arrays are already pointers.

Answer (score 4):

To make a character string representing the number in human-readable form, use snprintf(), like in code below.

To access the bytes of the double, use a union.  For example, union u { double d; char arr[8]; }

However, from your added comment, perhaps you mean to convert a number from characters to double.  See the atof() call in code below.  The code produces the following 4 output lines:

```
u.d = 2.132000     u.arr =  75 ffffff93 18 04 56 0e 01 40
res = 2.13200000
u.d = 37.456700     u.arr =  ffffffa6 0a 46 25 75 ffffffba 42 40
res = 37.45670000
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
union MyUnion { char arr[8];  double d; };

void printUnion (union MyUnion u) {
  int i;
  enum { LEN=40 };
  char res[LEN];
  printf ("u.d = %f     u.arr = ", u.d);
  for (i=0; i<8; ++i)
    printf (" %02x", u.arr[i]);
  printf ("\n");
  snprintf (res, LEN, "%4.8f", u.d);
  printf ("res = %s\n", res);
}
int main(void) {
  union MyUnion mu = { .d=2.132 };
  printUnion (mu);
  mu.d = atof ("37.4567");
  printUnion (mu);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In case someone looks at this, you can also try sprintf:

Example:

```
char charray[200];
double num = 11.1111111111111;

sprintf(charray, "%2.13f", num);
```

Answer (score 2):

Although I see some answers, I imagine you'd like to see code -- I'll just use snprintf although you might prefer a more secure form:

```
snprintf(arr, 8, "%2.4f", a);
```

more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ts7cx93(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

If what you are asking is how to find out what bytes make up the double value in memory, try this:

```
double a=2.132;
double darr[1] = { a };
char *arr = (char*) darr;
```

although you probably want unsigned char, not char

Answer (score -2):

double b=222.215;

```
        String bb=""+b;

        char[] tab=new char[bb.length()];

        for(int m=0;m<bb.length();m++)
        {
            tab[i]=bb.charAt(m);
        }//un tableau mtn qui contient notre resultat dans un tableua de char
```

Comment: This question is about `C`. Your answer doesn't look like `C`.