# How do I put an integer value into a char array? I want the number 1234 to be in the char array. I can't read it from a prompt

Tags: arrays, char, int

I'm new to C and I was doing okay in my class(online) until the last couple of programs.  They're getting more complicated and I'm not much of a strategist.  But, I'm trying and I'm frustrated.

I've been working on this one for a while (it's past due) and my ulimate goal is to convert a number into words for a paycheck.

What I'm trying to do here is convert the double value to an int and put the int into a char array, so that eventually the "array amount" will read (if pay was $1234.56) 001234.  Then I was thinking that I could do ifs or cases for each position (hundThous = 0, tenThous = 0, Thous = 1, etc..)  to convert it.  I'm getting stuck here, though and need help.

How do I put the value 1234 into the char array?

Also, in the function above, I called "checkWriter(money);" , where money is the double.  Is that correct?  I just want it to call this function to print the converted double to words.

```
    void checkWriter(double z)
    {
       double v;
       int w, y, cents;
       int b, c, x, length;
       char array[SIZE];
       char amount[SIZE]; /*size = 7, our largest value will be in the hundred thousands*/

       v = 100 * z; /*make z a whole number*/

       w = ((int)v); /*convert z to an integer w*/

       cents = w % 100; /*cents equals the remainder of w/100*/

       y = (w - cents)/100; /*y equals the converted integer minus cents, divided by 100*/

       sprintf(array, "%-6d", y); /* ATTEMPTING TO PUT y INTO array (saw this on google) */
       printf("%s\n\n", array); /* Just wanted to see if it worked.  It didn't.  I got -2big
                                   number.*/

       length = strnlen(array); /*find length of the value in array*/

       array[length] = '\0'; /* affix terminating null character to array */

       b = SIZE - length - 1; /* b is amount of zeroes needed */

       for(c = 0; c < length - 1; c++) { /* loops, plugging zeroes in amount until b=c, 
                                            then attaches array to amount */
          if(b == c) {
             amount[c] = '\0';
             strcat(amount, array);
          }
          else {
             amount[c] = '0';
          }
       }

       printf("%s\n\n", amount); /* Checking to see if it worked. Nope.  All zeroes. And 
                                    sometimes extra symbols at the end*/

       return;
    }
```

Would really appreciate help.  Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Please, look at [this](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/round.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462349/convert-double-value-to-a-char-array-in-c) articles.
Basically, you convert double to integer with rounding using

```
(int)double_value;
```

and then convert it to char array using

```
snprintf(arr, length, "%d", your_integer);
```