# What is the value of a unsigned long long in hex

Tags: c, floating-point, embedded, printf

I have this variable

```
unsigned long long latitude = 29.47667;
```

When I am converting this value to an array like this

```
    ar[7] = (uint8_t)((latitude >> 56) & 0xFF);
    ar[6] = (uint8_t)((latitude >> 48) & 0xFF);
    ar[5] = (uint8_t)((latitude >> 40) & 0xFF);
    ar[4] = (uint8_t)((latitude >> 32) & 0xFF);
    ar[3] = (uint8_t)((latitude >> 24) & 0xFF);
    ar[2] = (uint8_t)((latitude >> 16) & 0xFF);
    ar[1] = (uint8_t)((latitude >> 8) & 0xFF);
    ar[0] = (uint8_t)(latitude & 0xFF);
```

Then sending it to server using tcp socket. When I am sending I print the values in hex, then I get `0x1d` rest all zeros.

How to send the exact value to server while converting unsigned long long to int.

Answer (score 6):

`unsigned long long latitude = 29.47667` doesn't make much sense, `unsigned long long` is an integer type. So the variable only gets the truncated integer `29`.

That's why you get only `0x1d`, which is just `29` in hex.

Comment: I want a 64 bit variable. I have typedef signed long long int64_t, will that work?

Comment: @Ishmeet `long long` is at least 64 bit, it may be longer. So a portable way is to use `int64_t` in `stdint.h` if that's available.

Comment: I tried with `int` as well as `int64_t`, still got the same answer, it didn't work. Can you tell me please how is the value 29.47667 converted to hex. Does this happen on its own, or we need to do some computation?

Comment: @Ishmeet `29.47667` is a floating point value, why use an integer type to store it? It will be truncated as I said in the answer. Perhaps you are looking for `double`?

Comment: Ok, now I have `double latitude = 29.47667;`, I need something that converts this value to an 8 byte array, `ar[8]`.

Comment: will this work? --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462349/convert-double-value-to-a-char-array-in-c

Comment: @Ishmeet Seems so, be careful with endianess though.

Answer (score 4):

Read the double value byte by byte:

```c
double val = 29.47667;
double *ptr = &val;
uint8_t bytes[8];
register int i;

for(i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
{
   bytes[i] = *(((uint8_t*)ptr) + i);
   printf("%hhu", bytes[i]);
}
```

Do not use `unsigned long long` type for decimal value

**Another method** (if source will not be modified):

```c
double val = 29.47667;
double *ptr = &val;
uint8_t *cptr = (uint8_t*)ptr;
```

Now use *(cptr + i) directly to access/send value at byte **i.**

Comment: Or you can basically do `memcpy(bytes,&val,8);`, This has worked for me :).

Comment: +1 for the method, but I think (not sure) that `memcpy()` internally implements byte by byte copy only.

Comment: Suggest fixed width on your `printf()`  ("%03hhu").

Answer (score 2):

Convert double to hex and then hex to double.

Overlay a 64-bit integer with a `double`.  This supposes that the double is 8-bytes.  One can easily overlay other integer sizes should `double` be different.

Send the integer over your tcp socket and re-constitute as needed.

```
// 29.47667
403D7A070B8CFBFC
2.94766699999999986e+01
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

uint64_t MakeHex(double d) {
  union {
      double d;
      uint64_t u;
  } x;
  x.d = d;
  return x.u;
}

double MakeD(uint64_t u) {
  union {
      double d;
      uint64_t u;
  } x;
  x.u = u;
  return x.d;
}
int main() {
  uint64_t u = MakeHex(29.47667);
  printf("%0" PRIX64 "\n", u);
  double d = MakeD(u);
  printf("%.*le\n", DBL_DIG+2, d);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow! Great, but I cannot use PRIX64 and DBL_DIG+2 since I am using Stm32L Platform, and using UART as debug messages. But still I will try this without prints.

Answer (score -3):

you can call this function by including it in any headerfile

```
void dec_hex(long int num)      // Function Definition
{
long int rem[50],i=0,length=0;
while(num>0)
   {
      rem[i]=num%16;
      num=num/16;
      i++;
      length++;
   }

printf("Hexadecimal number : ");

for(i=length-1;i>=0;i--)
  {
    switch(rem[i])
    {
      case 10:
          printf("A");
          break;

      case 11:
          printf("B");
          break;

      case 12:
          printf("C");
          break;

      case 13:
          printf("D");
          break;

      case 14:
          printf("E");
          break;

      case 15:
          printf("F");
          break;

      default :
         printf("%ld",rem[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It will take my `double` value and convert it to `int`, as `long int num`, thus will not provide the right answer that is required.

Comment: This does nothing to address the OP's issue using decimal numbers.